# SolrJ not setting request handler

Tags: solr, solrj, solrcloud

I have a SolrCloud collection set up with multiple request handlers and I would like to access a non-default request handler called `/all` which is defined in solrconfig.xml.  This handler works fine when I search from the browser:

All handler:
[image]

However, when I search from SolrJ using `SolrQuery.setRequestHandler("all")`, I get 0 results.  SolrJ just puts a `qt=/all` into the query, so these are the browser results of the same query (SolrJ gets the same thing):

Select with qt=/all:
[image]

The same behavior is observed for all of our other handlers.  If a handler is not defined, Solr throws a different error if there is a leading '/' or defaults to select if there isn't a leading '/' so we know that isn't the problem.

So my question is, how can I get this to work in SolrJ?  Select has the default settings in solrconfig.xml and it needs to stay the default handler.  Searching around, the error seems to happen when there are duplicate IDs or the id field is not stored.  But if this was the case, none of the searching should work so I think something else must be going on here.

Comment: just a guess: /all could be reserved. Have you tried defining other unique handler end-point?

Comment: Yes we have two others and the same behavior is experienced with both of them.  If it helps, this SolrCloud is 6.0.1 and we a standalone version (5.3.0) with an identical index where all of the handlers (including /all) work properly using this method.

Comment: Ok. Have you tried posting over at the solr mailing list? Capturing attention of relevant folks there could help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15966517/using-terms-vs-selectqt-terms-in-solr Different question but perhaps the answer(s) will point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the issue kind of just resolved itself.  No changes were made but everything works properly now.  We think there could have been some indexing going on in the background or maybe something happened with Solr itself.  We may never know, but I am no longer able to reproduce the issue so I guess that works.

Thank you to everyone who tried to help.

Answer (score 0):

It's true that the visible effect in the "setRequestHandler" method is to just set the qt parameter.  But that's not the end of the story with SolrJ.

When a SolrJ request is processed, if the qt parameter contains a string starting with a forward slash, SolrJ will change "/select" in the URL path to the value contained in that parameter before it sends the request to Solr.  It will also send the qt parameter as-is to Solr, but the parameter itself usually doesn't matter.

If you send an actual request to Solr on the /select handler with qt set to "/all", Solr should ignore the qt parameter -- unless you set handleSelect to true in the requestDispatcher section of the solrconfig.xml.  This is not recommended -- because it means that you can *change* the index through the /select handler, simply by setting qt to "/update".

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/RequestDispatcher+in+SolrConfig#RequestDispatcherinSolrConfig-handleSelectElement

It's also possible that there's a bug in newer Solr, where using qt with handleSelect="true" doesn't work right.  I'm not sure whether that would actually be considered to be a bug or not.  It certainly wouldn't be recommended config.

What is the handleSelect setting in solrconfig.xml when you receive that exception?

Comment: -1: `handleSelect` is depreciated as of Solr 3.6.  From your link, " The default value "false" will ignore requests to /select **if a requestHandler is not explicitly registered with the name /select.**" (emphasis is mine).  As of Solr 3.6, a RequestHandler with the name /select is created by default so there is no reason to change this.  Before 3.6, the default RequestHandler was called /search.

Comment: Before 3.6, the example config contained a default handler with the name "default".  The example responded to requests on "/select" because that handler said default="true" and handleSelect was enabled.  From 3.6 on, the example had handleSelect disabled, and the default handler was actually named "/select" so that it would register on that URL path.  If the handleSelect parameter had been deprecated in 3.6, it would have been completely gone from 4.0 and later ... but the documentation I linked above is for current versions, and at the time I linked it, that was 6.x.

Comment: Okay, sure.  Depreciated was the wrong word.  No longer used maybe.  It was kept around for backwards compatibility according to the JIRA discussion about it.  Regardless, this answer isn't relevant to the question as I mention using the select handler in my post.